# How to get through CSRF Protection with Ajax in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

I want to send a Ajax post request but i get some issues with CSRF.

Here is my js code :

```
 function sendAjaxRequest(index){
    var token = $('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr('content')
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : token } });
    $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
        data: '{"value":"10"}', 
       dataType: 'json',
       url: "http://localhost/laravel/public/",
    });
 }
```

Here is my route from my laravel routes.php file :

`Route::post('/','AjaxController@updateOrder'`);

Here is my console (jQuery issue) :

```
POST http://localhost/kaemo/public/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is my network preview :

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set CSRF token in `X-CSRF-TOKEN` like,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

And add the below code in your `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`, add the `tokenMatch()` method to this.

```
<?php
    /**
     * Determine if the session and input CSRF tokens match.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function tokensMatch($request)
    {
        // If request is an ajax request, then check to see if token matches token provider in
        // the header. This way, we can use CSRF protection in ajax requests also.
        $token = $request->ajax() ? $request->header('X-CSRF-Token') : $request->input('_token');

        return $request->session()->token() == $token;
    }
```

Read more [[Laravel5] TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken](http://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2015-laravel5-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the token into your `data`

```
var token = "{{csrf_token()}}";
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
    data: '{"value":"10", _token: token}', 
   dataType: 'json',
   url: "http://localhost/laravel/public/",
});
```

Comment: ehh just realised that your url seems incorrect, try using only http://localhost/laravel ?